# python module imports and conda commands not working (possible homebrew - anadonda installs conflict)

Tags: python, installation, import, anaconda, conda

I'm a python beginner, having some issues importing modules. I tried importing numpy and scipy in jupyter notebook but it returned a ['ModuleNotFoundError'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRDgP.png). I assume its because of the way I installed things but I don't know how to fix it. First I installed python and python 3 (3.9.4) via homebrew. Yesterday I also installed anaconda via brew command. After the anaconda installation instead of  python 2.7.12, I'm running python 2.7.16 now. 'import numpy' is working there but not in python3. Can someone help me get to the bottom of this? Did anaconda install a 2nd python2 instance on my system in a different location that is now being used as default or update the already existing one? In my anaconda folder I have python and python3.8. How can I get my default python3 (3.9.4) to also access the anadonda packages? Or would it make more sense to update the anaconda python3 and make it default? Also, conda commands are not working, e.g. returning [-bash: conda: command not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18P5N.png). My anaconda is located at '/usr/local/anaconda3' not the default location mentioned in the official anaconda doc '/Users/your-username/anaconda3', in case that might cause any issues here.

Somebody gave me a tip, saying:
"Can you go into the vituralenv you have created via anaconda and enter ' pip list ' . You then can see what packages are installed in that virtual environment.  Also make sure to not install anything for python 2.x. Python 2 is not the version you will be using so always install everyting to python3. (in the vituralenv enviorment use pip3 install packagename)"

It doesn't really solve my problem though I guess, cause I want to use the conda packages with the default python3 on my system, since I think its more convenient for now then using a virtualenv. Beside the fact that conda commands are not working.

I'm working on a MBP with macos 10.13 in case its relevant. Sorry for the many questions but I'm new to this and pretty confused.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. I used the -pip command to install the packages. I found that jupyter was not using my default python3 kernel, where all my packages get installed to. With ipykernel I could install the kernel for jupyter notebook to use. Unfortunately with anaconda I installed another python instance, meaning I should make conda work with my default python as well, but I leave that for another time.